# Ruby on Rails 5.2 Upgrade | ArgumentError (A class was passed to `:class_name` but we are expecting a string.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading a Ruby on Rails application to 5.2 from 5.0 and am receiving this error when attempting to call any of my models that have a relationship defined:

```
ArgumentError (A class was passed to :class_name but we are expecting a string.)
```

Code causing issues

```
  belongs_to :manufacturer,
             foreign_key: :org_id_mnfr,
             class_name: Organization::Manufacturer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the new Rails version. Rails 5.2 no longer accepts non-quoted class names with the `class_name:` attribute. You need to change all instances in which `class_name:` is being passed an actual model, rather than a string of the model name.

eg.
`Organization::Manufacturer` becomes `'Organization::Manufacturer'`

If your application has many instances of this as mine did, you will probably want a way to automatically change these. Here is how I used `Atom` editor and `Regex` to find and replace all instances of this.

**Find All with Regex Enabled:**

Find in project: `class_name: ([^'][\w|:]*[^'|,| |\n])`

Replace With: `class_name: '$1'`

File/Directory Pattern `*.rb`

**What this is doing:**
Find all instances of `class_name` that are not already quoted and capture the Class name within capture group 1. We then replace the entire find by with the static string `class_name:` and then the first capture group with single quotes around it.

This results in: `class_name: Organization::Manufacturer` becoming `class_name: 'Organization::Manufacturer'`

This can handle the class name attribute having a space , a new line `\n`, or a comma `,` character after. But there may be some instances in which this causes errors so please double check the replaces before hitting Commit!